# Rails, route_path breaks when there is @ symbol in username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I get a RoutingError whenever a username has an `@` symbol in it:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show", :username=>"abc@shin.com"}
```

My routes looks like this:

```
match 'users/:username' => 'users#show', :as => :show_other_user
```

And my view:

```
<% for user in @users %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= image_tag avatar_url(user, 50) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to user.name, show_other_user_path(:username => user.username) %></td>
    <td><%= common_friends(current_user, user).size %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Everything works find if the username doesn't have the `@` symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your route isn't breaking because of the `@`, it is breaking because of the `.`. Rails will see the `.` and think you're trying to specify a format (i.e. `.html`, `.xml`, ...). You need to kludge around the auto-format detection stuff a little bit by updating your route with something like this:

```
match 'users/:username' => 'users#show', :as => :show_other_user, :constraints => { :username => /.*/ }
```

The `:constraints` should sort out your routing problems (you'd use `:requirements` for Rails 2).

Comment: This doesn't work, I get the error:
`No route matches {:requirements=>{:username=>/.*/}, :controller=>"users", :action=>"show", :username=>"abc@shin.com"}`

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee: Sorry, `:requirements` is Rails2, you'd want `:constraints` for Rails3.